# Constants in $\|p\|_{L^\infty}\leq C\|p\|_{L^2}$ for polynomials $p$

Tags: inequality, reference-request, polynomials

Let $P$ be a space of polynomials on $[0,1]^d$. 
What is the best possible constant $C$ in 
$$
\|p\|_{L^\infty}\leq C\|p\|_{L^2} \quad\forall p\in P?
$$
I am interested in any result, for polynomial spaces of your choice.

Comment: What exactly is $P$?  Is it a set of polynomials of some bounded degree?

Comment: As I said in the question, I am interested in results for any space of polynomials. For example, $P$ could be all univariate polynomials of degree lower than $k$.

Comment: Does such a constant $C$ even exist?